# Why does my log4j2 properties configuration not log to console nor a separate file?

Tags: java, file, log4j2

I have been trying to log messages from a specific class. I only want the specific messages from that class to log to a separate file and nothing else. I cant seem to get it right and I have tried multiple configurations including XML format. Id be helpful for feedback on my configuration. (see Below )

```
log4j2.appender.solrindexlog.type=RollingFile
log4j2.appender.solrindexlog.name=SolrIndexLog
log4j2.appender.solrindexlog.fileName=${NAME_LOG_DIR}/tomcat/solrindex.log
log4j2.appender.solrindexlog.filePattern=${NAME_LOG_DIR}/tomcat/solrindexlog-%d{yyyyMMdd}.log
log4j2.appender.solrindexlog.layout.type=PatternLayout
log4j2.appender.solrindexlog.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
log4j2.appender.solrindexlog.policies.type=Policies
log4j2.appender.solrindexlog.policies.time.type=TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
log4j2.appender.solrindexlog.policies.time.interval=2
log4j2.appender.solrindexlog.policies.time.modulate=true
log4j2.appender.solrindexlog.policies.size.type=SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
log4j2.appender.solrindexlog.policies.size.size=100MB
log4j2.appender.solrindexlog.strategy.type=DefaultRolloverStrategy
log4j2.appender.solrindexlog.strategy.max=5

log4j2.logger.solrindexlog.name=se.package.name
log4j2.logger.solrindexlog.level=debug
log4j2.logger.solrindexlog.appenderRefs=stdout
log4j2.logger.solrindexlog.appenderRef.stdout.ref=STDOUT

log4j2.rootLogger.level=info
log4j2.rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref=STDOUT
log4j2.rootLogger.appenderRef.solrindexlog.ref=SolrIndexLog
log4j2.rootLogger.appenderRefs=stdout,solrindexlog
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below configuration file -

```
appender.solrindexlog.type=RollingFile
appender.solrindexlog.name=SolrIndexLog
appender.solrindexlog.fileName=${NAME_LOG_DIR}/tomcat/solrindex.log
appender.solrindexlog.filePattern=${NAME_LOG_DIR}/tomcat/solrindexlog-%d{yyyyMMdd}.log
appender.solrindexlog.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.solrindexlog.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
appender.solrindexlog.policies.type=Policies
appender.solrindexlog.policies.time.type=TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.solrindexlog.policies.time.interval=2
appender.solrindexlog.policies.time.modulate=true
appender.solrindexlog.policies.size.type=SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.solrindexlog.policies.size.size=100MB
appender.solrindexlog.strategy.type=DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.solrindexlog.strategy.max=5

logger.se.package.name.name=se.package.name
logger.se.package.name.level=debug
logger.se.package.name.additivity = false
logger.se.package.name.appenderRef.solrindexlog.ref= SolrIndexLog
logger.se.package.name.appenderRef.stdout.ref= STDOUT

rootLogger.level=info
rootLogger.additivity = false
rootLogger.appenderRef.solrindexlog.ref= SolrIndexLog
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref= STDOUT
```

Please change other parts of the configuration file that are not written in above configuration file like `ConsoleAppender` etc.

Also, as per this configuration file, all logs message will go in file as well as in console.